# Check an HTML document for proper opening and closing tags

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have been learning about stacks (which I created a class for) in Python lately and I learned that you can use them to check if parentheses are balanced, which is each opening symbol has a corresponding closing symbol and the pairs of parentheses are properly nested.

Now I am trying to use a stack to do the same but with HTML. So for example, my program would take the following document-

```
<html> 
   <head>
     <title>
        Example
     </title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <h1>Hello, world</h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

and check it to make sure that it has proper opening and closing tags.

I just don't even have an idea on where to start and I'm very confused. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: run it through a dom parser. most dom parsers are picky and will barf if the html is malformed.

Comment: Just read the document character for character, when you encounter a `<`, start “listening” until you see the end of the tag name (a space or a `>`). Then put that name on a stack. If you encounter a tag name that starts with a `/`, then you want to remove the top element from the stack. If the top element didn’t have the same name, then the document was malformed. Finally, note that HTML (as a subset of SGML) does not require closing tags, only XHTML (as a subset of XML) does. So you cannot use this for arbitrary HTML documents.

Comment: What makes you think a stack is the right tool?  I'm not saying it isn't, but you seem pretty sure for someone who has no idea how to start.

Comment: @ScottHunter It sounds to me as if OP wanted to apply the stack idea on a HTML/XML structure, as an exercise. That sounds totally fine to me.

Comment: @poke: I didn't say it wasn't, but explaining *why* is a useful precursor to figuring out *how*.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to approach the problem this way, think about what you did before:

You used a stack to keep track of `(`, `[`, or `{`.

What's the difference between `(` and `<html>`? One of these is just a collection of characters. So change your code - instead of reading a single character and placing that on the stack, read the *tag* and place that on the stack instead.

You may also want to decide if you want to ensure that you've got some valid(ish) HTML - i.e. what happens if you encounter `<<html>`?

Answer (score 0):

```
#Old interesting question:use usual stack for pop, push, and peek 
#inserted space for each ">x" and "x<" where x is any char, 
import re
text='''<html>
<head>
<title>
Example
</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello, world</h1>
</body>
</html>''' 
def check_html_balance(text):
    s=Stack()
    x=text.replace('<', ' <'); y=x.replace('>', '> ')
    a=[w for w in y.split() if re.search('<\S+>',w)]
    b=[w for w in a if "/" not in w]
    c=[w for w in a if "/"  in w]
    for w in text.split():
        if w in b:
            s.push(w)
        elif not s.is_empty() and (w in c) and (w.replace('/','')==s.peek()):                               
            s.pop()
    return s.is_empty()
check_html_balance(text)
```

Comment: Thank you, but `for w in text.split():` should be `for w in y.split():`

Answer (score 0):

```
    # A second, shorter solution without replacing "x<" by "x <"...  
    text='''<html>
    <head>
    <title>
    Example
    </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Hello, world</h1>
    </body>
    </html>''' 
    import re
    def check_balance(text):
    L=re.split('(<[^>]*>)', text)[1::2]
    s=Stack()
    for word in L:
        if ('/' not in word):
            s.push(word)
        elif not s.is_empty() and (word.replace('/','')==s.peek()):                               
            s.pop()
    return s.is_empty()
check_balance(text)
```